# PhpMyAdmin not working - XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've installed **XAMPP Windows 1.8.2** and after installing and turning on Apache & MySQL, I can't load my PMA webpage: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` . It **still loading**, but nothing happens. I really don't know, what I am doing wrong. Also I can't use any PHP application, which is trying to use MySQL connection (like Symfony2). If I turn off MySQL in XAMPP Control Panel and trying to reload this URL, **same problem**.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: DO you see something with just http://localhost ? Also, which Windows version?

Comment: Check if your firewall blocks ports 80 and 443.

Comment: To: Marc Delisle i don't understand what do you mean in first question. I am using Windows XP SP 3.

@user1929959 I think yes, but I am not very sure, where I can check this. I think yes because after trying to first Staring MySQL, Firewall asks me to unblock this application and I confirmed it.

Comment: @MarcDelisle means what do you see when you click on the following link: http://localhost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this point, I would recommend for you to use 1.5.1 version of Xammp right away. Long story why (shortly, this is a Windows matter and with this answer its irrelevant).

So....

1. Uninstal that version
2. find 1.5.1
3. Install

However, when you install 1.5.x you might have problems with PMA when larger tables are loaded. This sorts things out

1. Find PMA version 2.11.11.3 package (this baby is really stable)
2. Unpack
3. c/p all files from pack to your xampp/PMA folder and overwrite everything :P

And thats it.

You may, later on, upgrade PHP to ie 5.3.0 and there is a trick how to do that painless somewhere on www (google ekhm) but cant remember where exactly. Enjoy.

ps: If you dont like this answer, youre probably on XP and you need something like vcredist_x86.exe but problems wont stop there ;)

Comment: So I will have problems with php_apc.dll and php_intl.dll again?

Comment: Lets just say that VC9 versions work awkward even when dlls are sorted out + eats up much more memory and stuff like that. You wont be amazed shortly at all. So, use this answer I gave you and create your own, great XAMPP. It will take about 2 hours to complete and problems will gone. I run 151 XAMPP with 530 PHP & PMA 2.11 like a baby. XAMPP is a great tool, but over time their versions became problems. This answer will keep your work OK until someone creates XAMPP as it were before.

Comment: So solution without problems is for example WAMP?

Comment: I dont use WAMP for 10 years from now, so have no idea what you will find there today. I felt in love with XAMPP since it was a great, so simple, easy to install and all-in-one tool. Now, if i need some update (like PHP, Mysql or PMA), I just do updates by my own due to problems that occured like yours for example. XAMPP is more popular I think and you will find more community help there what is also important.

Comment: Problem was not in XAMPP but Symfony2. But there is my new question where? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684661/symfony2-welcome-page-will-lag-mysql-and-page-wont-open , but thanks for answer, I'll mark this answer as best, because without it, I will don't know, where is the problem.

Comment: Overthere says you installed - WAMP :P So is it WAMp or XAMpp lol? :)

Comment: I've unistalled XAMPP and then installed WAMP if problem persists.

Comment: Never mind. Just try to learn about my answer here and after that, only websites may be a problem. Its really easy. Anyway, Smyph2 and PMA are spearated problems. If PMA works.. symph2 is a problem.  Now most important thing is that PMA is online. Good luck! Ill try to help again and try to answer your problem there.

Comment: My problem is now with Symphony2. I want to run him (Welcome page). Config file is OK.

Comment: Im writting answer about it there, be patient. Yeah, problem is configuring now WAMP with Symphony (otherwise Symphony would work as well as PMA right?). Since you have new installation (of WAMP and PMA) you must add user account via PMA also! Complicated I know..

Comment: Ahh something's wrong. If I tryed to login via PMA, it still loading after sending data.

Comment: And now i cannot open PMA after restarting WAMP.

Comment: NOID.. I cant help you from here although I would gladly :(((( I forgot how WAMP looks like, and have no idea what Symphony does :( But I know that if PMA is on.. Virtual host and mysql are fine. What you gonna do now?